# Update dataframe 1 using two columns in dataframe 2 in python

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I want to update Freq column in df1 using Freq column in data frame 2 as shown below,

data = {'Cell':[1,2,3,4,'10-05','10-09'], 'Freq':[True, True,True,True,True,True]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

Dataframe 1

[Dataframe 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVE6D.png)

Dataframe 2

data2 = {'Cell-1':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],'Cell-2':[1,2,3,4,'10-05','10-09',1,2,3,4,'10-05','10-09'] ,'Freq':[True, False,True,False,True,True,True, False,True,False,True,False]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

[Dataframe 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLOda.png)

df1 column 1 has keys while column 2 is corresponding value which in this case is either True or False.

Lets take for example key = 1 in Dataframe 1. This key = 1 has multiple values in Dataframe 2 as shown in the figure. The multiple values for this key = 1 in dataframe 2 is due to values in Column 2, Dataframe 2 which in turn are keys to Dataframe 1 which I want to update in column 2 of df1.

Algorithm in action figure
[Alogrithm in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byy2o.png)

Comment: This sample is a little too confusing. Perhaps using letters as column names (say, [A,B] for df1 and [C,D,E] for df2) can make your question clearer. It will also help to post a smaller sample set and the result you want.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.